# How to import boost module from C++ to python?

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

Following is the c++ code which I want to import.

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <string>

/*
 * This is the C++ function we write and want to expose to Python.
 */
const std::string hello() {
    return std::string("hello, zoo");
}

/*
 * This is a macro Boost.Python provides to signify a Python extension module.
 */
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(zoo) {
    // An established convention for using boost.python.
    using namespace boost::python;

    // Expose the function hello().
    def("hello", hello);
}
```

The following code is python script.

```
import zoo     # In zoo.cpp we expose hello() function, and it now exists 
                  in the zoo module.

assert 'hello' in dir(zoo)   # zoo.hello is a callable.

assert callable(zoo.hello)   # Call the C++ hello() function from Python.

print zoo.hello()
```

When I try to run the script, I am not getting "hello, zoo" at the terminal as output. Where am I making the mistake?

Following is the error message I am getting:

import: not authorized `zoo' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1028.
./visit_zoo.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token`('
./visit_zoo.py: line 3: `assert 'hello' in dir(zoo)'

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you forgetting to indicate the script should be run by Python, as I did?

You can either include the python executable in the header of your script file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
```

and make the file executable or call the script with Python:

```
$ python <filename>
```